# Переписать функцию под Android 5.1

Tags: android, функции, override

Пишу приложение на API 22 (Android 5.1). Чтобы не начинать с нуля поискал и нашёл в интернете исходники приложения под API 7. Android Studio находит в этой функции ошибки (в `InputMethodManager`и его методе `.showSoftInput`). Мне сложно сходу понять, как переписать данный код, поэтому обращаюсь к Вам.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        if (edFind.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
            edFind.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.i("Main", "Hide search bar");
        } else {
            edFind.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (edFind.requestFocus())
                Log.i("Main", "Focus set");
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.showSoftInput(edFind, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            Log.i("Main", "Show search bar");
        }
        RefreshList();
        return true;
    }
```

Update 0.
Пишет что Class requires API level 3 (current min is 1), подчёркивает красным и отсвечивает тоже красным.

Comment: Какие ошибки находит? Можно поподробнее, что именно пишется?

Comment: До понедельника сказать не смогу, я уже не на практике, где IDE исправно работает

Comment: Скорее всего не ошибку, а предупреждение (жёлтым подчёркнуто?), в котором говорится, что обращение к переменной `mgr` может вызвать `NullPointerException`, так как метод `getSystemService` может вернуть `null`, если в системе нет такой службы.

Comment: Посмотрел, добавил в пост

Comment: По моему очевидно, что если ваше текущее API 3 (как указано в ошибке), то методы из API 7 в нем работать не будут, так как, формально, еще не существуют и будут добавлены только через 4 API. Здесь напрашивается вопрос, зачем вам поддерживать такое древнее API/ Если есть какая то необходимость в этой поддержке, то такой метод или класс (выполняющий аналогичную функцию) вам придется написать самому